# How to get complete link of an image with python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to make a crawler which goes to the web page and downloads all the images available on that page. My code looks like this

```
import random
import urllib.request
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_images(url):
    code = requests.get(url)
    text = code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
    for img in soup.findAll('img'):
        src = img.get('src')
        download_image(src)


def download_image(url):
    name = random.randrange(1, 100)
    image_name = str(name) + ".jpg"
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, image_name)

get_images("http://www.any_url.com/")
```

Now many images usually don't contain their full URL in their `src` tag. Now, my question is that how can i get full URL of the images so that i can download them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full url of your image is **hostname of your webpage** + **relative path in src tag**.

e.g

Url of your webpage is `http://example.com/foo/bar.html`

and image src tag is : `<img src="/image/smiley.png">`,

then absolute url of your image will be `http://example.com/image/smiley.png`

It's easy to perform this operation using inbuilt function `urljoin()` :

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin
webpage_url = 'http://example.com/foo/bar.html'
src = '/folder/big/a.jpg'
urljoin(webpage_url, src)
```